# Lead Conversion to Opportunity

Tags: lead-conversion

I need to convert Leads into just an Opportunity because for various reasons the Account and Contacts for the Lead record will have been created separately. From the convertLead() docs is seems that if you use this method then you *have* to create an Account and Contact record on conversion.

> Use convertLead() to convert a Lead into an Account and Contact, as well as (optionally) an Opportunity.

Is this correct?

If so, then I would have to create the Opportunity separately which is fine except that I still need to mark the Lead as converted, but I see that the `isConverted` field is non-writable.

Would really like to find out about methods to convert a Lead into just an Opportunity and whether I can explicitly set a Lead to `isConverted` by code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dml_convertLead.htm):

There you have the ability to provide an existing AccountId and ContactId with the methods setAccountId() and setContactId(), respectively.

You just have to make sure that your contact is associated with the account you provide in AccountId, and if you use PersonAccounts, don't provide the ContactId

> **setAccountId** Sets the ID of the account into which the lead
> will be merged. This value is required only when updating an existing
> account, including person accounts. Otherwise, if setAccountID is
> specified, a new account is created.
>
> **setContactId** Sets the
> ID of the contact into which the lead will be merged (this contact
> must be associated with the account specified with setAccountId, and
> setAccountId must be specified). This value is required only when
> updating an existing contact.Important If you are converting a lead
> into a person account, do not specify setContactId or an error will
> result. Specify only setAccountId of the person account. If
> setContactID is specified, then the application creates a new contact
> that is implicitly associated with the account.

Comment: Ah. Of course. I read that a few times, but for some reason I completely blanked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: please mark my answer as correct, so other people with the same question will later on discover it easily ;) and an upvote would also be appreciated.